# Appyling Schengen Family Visa of my parents. My parents' surname in their passport is different from my passport, will there be any issue?

Tags: schengen-visas, suriname

I stay in Belgium and want to call my parents to visit us for a short stay.
However, my parents' surname on their passport is different than those stated on my passport.
Seeking guidance on how to process on the above, will there be any issue, or do I need to file an affidavit stating that both names belong to the same person?

Comment: Does your passport actually contain the information about your parents' names? Do you have other documents attesting to your parentage (birth certificates etc.)?

Comment: As far I know there is no Schengen Family visa. For a short visit they need usual B visa. In any case: the tag: suriname is a country (and not "surname"). But why do we have such tag with a small `S`?